# Building python package with extensions leads to segmentation fault when using Conda

Tags: python, c++, conda, ctypes, distutils

I created a python package with an additional c++ extension which is wrapped using ctypes.
Since this is a c++ class I define an external c interface in the header files.

```
extern "C" {
void* create_reader(int key);
void  release_reader(void* reader);
void*  read_data(void* reader);
}
```

Then I use ctypes to load the shared library created from this

```
lib_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(fpath, "api*.so"))[0]
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)

lib.read_data.argtype = ctypes.c_void_p
lib.read_data.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)
```

Furthermore I create a class to wrap the c++ class
the ctypes pointer is than wrapped to a numpy array  (this is just some part of the code)

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self._reader = lib.create_shm_reader(ikey)
    def get_buffer(self):
      
        ptr = lib.read_data(self._reader)
        nx, ny = 100, 100
        size = 3
  
        return np.copy(np.ctypeslib.as_array(ptr, shape=shape))
```

So basically the c++ reader creates some pointer to a memory buffer which is than
mapped to a numpy array.

The c++ code is build with `distutils.Extension` into a *.so lib.

As long as I build this package in a python virtual env with cython installed everything works.
In the c++ part some data is generated and than transfered to a numpy array which I can read from python.

However when I use Conda (in particular miniconda) with a clean conda env including cython,
when calling  the read_data function  I immediately receive a segmentation fault.
To me it seems that Conda has some issues linking the shared library,
since the read_data function is called and immediately a segfault occurs ( tested with printf)

For both cases the ctypes version is `1.1.0` and python is `3.6.9`.
So what is the reason this segfault occurs when using conda.

I appreciate any feedbacks.
BR jrsm

## UPDATE1:

I install the package from the repository root with `pip install .` 
So also in conda I use pip to install the package.
So my assumption is also that pip uses different settings than during the build then during the runtime in anaconda ?

## UPDATE2:

I provide a full running example in this github repository:
https://github.com/jr7/condatest

the README explains in detail how to setup and execute.

Comment: `.argtypes` not `.argtype` and the value must be a sequence.  Since it isn't set properly the argument is passed as a 32-bit int by default and truncates the pointer...assuming a 64-bit system.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I changed `argtype` to `argtypes` and used a sequence. However, I still get a segmentation fault when using `conda`.